# old wiring inside wall gets voltage when shared switch is used - safe and to code?

Tags: electrical, wiring, fans

I had someone run a constant hot to a new fan so it could operate with a remote. They left the old wiring inside the ceiling and it’s still contacted to a shared switch that operates other lights. The old wiring has nuts and electrical tape on the ends. When I turn on the lights I can see from a voltage meter that the old wires are hot. I only noticed this when I took the fan down to do some painting around the base. The wiring is inside the metal box that is part of the fan mount.

Is this safe and the correct procedure and is it to code?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the new wire (the constant hot) run to the fan is up to code, capping off the old wires in the metal fan box is fine.

You might consider also wrapping the wire nuts with electrician's tape for good measure.

Comment: thanks - looks like the person who did this used nuts AND taped around where the wires meets the nut. I hate the idea that a wire is live when in my wall when I have other lights on but it seems this is fine. I guess the ground says exposed.